# Question on prop 0.18 by Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology

Here is prop 0.18 from Hatcher: if $(X_1,A)$ is CW pair and we have attaching maps $f,g:A\rightarrow X_0$ that are homotopic, then $X_0\sqcup_f X_1$ is homotopy equivalent to $X_0\sqcup_g X_1$ relative to $X_0$.

Hatcher says if $F:A\times I\rightarrow X_0$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$, consider the space $X_0\sqcup_F(X_1\times I)$; this contains both $X_0\sqcup_f X_1$ and $X_0\sqcup_g X_1$ as subspaces. In the online errata by Hatcher, he explains that this follows from the fact if $q:X\rightarrow Y$ is any quotient map, $A\subset X$ is a closed saturated set, then $q|_A$ is a quotient map.

But $X_0\sqcup X_1$ is not saturated (wrt the quotient map induced by $F$). I think instead Hatcher's observation gives that $X_0\sqcup_F(X_1\times\{0\}\bigcup A\times I)$ is a subspace. Can anyone please explain this to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_0\sqcup_F(X_1\times\{0\}\bigcup A\times I)$ under quotient topology is homeomorphic to $X_0\sqcup_f X_1$.

Comment: Then I guess above should be homeomorphic to $X_0\sqcup_{g}X_1$ as well. But is it true $X_0 \sqcup_{f} X_1 \simeq X_0 \sqcup_{g} X_1$ (homeomorphic)

Comment: @MahammadYusifov it's not true in general. The point all the points of $\bigcup A\times I$ in $X_0\sqcup_F(X_1\times\{0\}\bigcup A\times I)$ are glued to some points in $X_1$, so $X_0\sqcup_F(X_1\times\{0\}\bigcup A\times I)$ is the same as $X_0\sqcup_F(X_1\times\{0\}\bigcup A\times {0})$. The points of $A\times {0}$ are glued to $X_1$ according to $f$, not $g$.